# Can I make my own barcode pattern based on existing pattern?

Tags: software, intellectual-property

There is a number of barcode patterns out there.

One of them is RSS-14 (aka GS1 DataBar). It's even been standartized in ISO/IEC 24724:2011.

Now, while I like the general format of the barcode, I want to make it shorter to use in software development / advertising. I'm not going to patent my new format or anything and I'm going to use an open source software library.

Am I violating some RSS-14 patent here by doing so?
Am I correct in assuming that if it was ISO standartized, it means I can build upon it?

Comment: How do you anticipate *anyone* else reading the code if it's non-standard? I mean, no barcode scanner is going to read it.

Comment: I will make my own app that reads the code.

Comment: You'd have to do a proper patent search, I think.  That's not something this site can do for you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a question about technical implementation. This is a question about intellectual property.

Comment: ISO standards are not necessarily open source or public domain.

Comment: Nate got it right. You need to find the patent (if any) first, and only then ask whether what you plan on doing infringes on that patent.

Comment: Any advice on how I can find the patent? So far I've tried Google patent search and that wasn't exactly helpful.

Answer (score -2):

I am not at all familiar with the technology in question, but what I've understood is that your are trying to shorten an existing barcode pattern, while many barcode patterns already exist, here's my common sense answer:

1. Are you sure *RSS-14 (aka GS1 DataBar)* is patented ?  Try finding if *RSS-14 (aka GS1 DataBar)* has been used by any one else for whatever purpose it can be used.

*Now, while I like the general format of the barcode, I want to make it shorter to use in software development / advertising.*

2. Has anyone made barcode shorter earlier to use in software development, does it sounds an easily thinkable work for people in your industry/place of work.

You think your use is new, can people with similar skills like you are having, come up with such use or piece of program ? Will it be logical or too easy for them to come up with it or you think its unique & won't be easily attainable by them.

People ask the above question before patenting their work but it helps.

*I'm not going to patent my new format*

3. Your written piece of program automatically gets copyrighted but still you can get it registered through copyright office. I think its an easy process and won't cost much.

Also in your given facts you'll be creating an app other than shortened code i.e an additional piece of program (i am guessing that it won't involve any piece of RSS-14) , so this app should be free of IPR issues.